# How to call a method on an item that you're formatting inside a string in python?

Tags: python, string, methods, formatting

`'aBcDe'.lower()` works fine and returns `'abcde'`.

So why can't I do this : `'{0.lower()}'.format('aBcDe')` ?

It returns the following error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'lower()'`

My guess is that the code figures out that the attribute is the entire string `'lower()'`, instead of `'lower'` and it just doesn't work. So how can I call a method in this fashion?

Answer (score 1):

You're right; Python thinks that `.lower()` is an attribute of the string `'aBcDe'`. You can fix this by moving the call to `.lower()` to the parameter to `.format()`:

```py
'{0}'.format('aBcDe'.lower())
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `format` method, you can't put something you want to evaluate inside the curly braces. Here are two (of several ways around this):

```py
'{0}'.format('aBcDe'.lower())
```

or use an f-string:

```py
f"{'aBcDe'.lower()}"
```